# What does <?= mean?

Tags: php, php-shorttags

whats the meaning of this line

```
<input type=text name="name" value="<?= $name ?>
```

if we are to declare as PHP shouldn't we write `<?php instead of <?=`

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`<?=` are PHP short open tags, which can be enabled (or disabled) via the [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) directive in `php.ini` *(quoting)* :

> This directive also affects the
>   shorthand `<?=` , which is identical
>   to `<? echo` . Use of this shortcut
>   requires `short_open_tag` to be `on`.

And:

> Also if disabled, you must use the
>   long form of the PHP open tag (`<?php
>   ?>` ).

This means your portion of code :

```
<input type=text name="name" value="<?= $name ?>
```

Is equivalent to this one :

```
<input type=text name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>
```

But only **when short open tags are enabled**.

And, as a sidenote : short open tags are not always enabled -- in fact, they are disabled by default, with recent versions of PHP.

Which means it might be wise to not depend on those, at least if you want to deploy your application on servers on which you are not administrator.

Comment: I agree, relying on short tags is asking for a broken heart when you deploy on a server that is configured to not allow them :)

Comment: In defense of short tags, they're invaluable if you use PHP as its own templating layer.  Additionally, it can be set PHP_INI_PERDIR -- i.e., in .htaccess on a per-app basis.

Comment: "<?=" won't be deprecated on PHP6 and since PHP5.3 "is now always available, regardless of the short_open_tag php.ini option."

Comment: I know this is an old answer but it may be useful to others if you updated it to reflect the current documentation. In particular, the fact that [since 5.4.0, `<?=` is enabled, even without short tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).

Comment: Why if I add a function at the variable inside the shortcourt tag(like:  `<? addslashes($string); ?>` )  didn't print anything?
It's an error adding the `echo` function using the shortcourt (`<? echo addslashes($string); ?>`), or is better use it in normal `<?php ?>` tags?

Answer (score 10):

`<?= ... ?>` is [shorthand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) for `<?php echo ... ?>`

Answer (score 3):

using short tags is generally frowned upon nowadays but it's still an option in the php.ini. It's fine, it's just poor coding style and has some repercussions if you use multiple dynamic languages.

Comment: Not to mention short tags are deprecated as of php6

Comment: Considering PHP 6 is far from finished (it's not even in alpha stage yet), things can change -- even if it probably will not for this specific point.

Comment: PHP6?  who?  what?  where?  when?

Comment: I know this is an old answer but it may be useful to others if you updated it to reflect the current documentation. In particular, the fact that [since 5.4.0, `<?=` is enabled, even without short tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).