# What does this symbol mean in PHP <?=

Tags: php, symbols

What does this symbol mean in PHP `<?=`?

Example usage:

```
<h2>Manage Role: > (<?= $myACL->getRoleNameFromID($_GET['roleID']); ?>)</h2>
```

Comment: Whether you use short `<?=` or long `<?php echo`, you still need `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does <?= mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959256/what-does-mean)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does '<?=' mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020445/what-does-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's functionally the same as `<?php echo $myACL->getRoleNameFromID($_GET['roleID']); ?>`

Comment: Although it is important to note that prior to PHP 5.4.0 the short echo syntax only works with the short_open_tag configuration setting enabled, which is off by default.

Comment: Is there any execution performance difference between '<?php' & '<?='

Answer (score 13):

To add to Mark's answer: The short_tags option must be enabled for the `<?=` syntax to be valid. This presents a major portability problem when moving to a server that has this option disabled.

[See the PHP Manual for more info on short tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Comment: Couldn't the user simply call `ini_set('short_open_tag', 1)` to override? Or if short tags are disabled, is the `ini_set` function normally disabled as well?

Comment: @Doug: actually, by the time the user was allowed to call `ini_set`, the file was already parsed.  So it's too late at that point.  The best alternative is a directive in `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf` if you can.

Comment: MikeB, the `short_open_tag` option no longer applies to `<?=` [as of PHP 5.4](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php).

Answer (score 6):

It's the PHP Short Tag equivalent of printing.

> From the PHP INI:
>
> *Using short tags is discouraged when developing code meant for redistribution
>   ;     since short tags may not be supported on the target server.*

See "[Are PHP Short Tags Acceptable to Use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)" on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
The <?= ... > tag says to execute whatever is in ... and output the results.
```