# What does '<?=' mean in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax

```
<?php

$a=1;

?>
<?=$a;?>
```

What does `<?=` mean exactly?

Comment: Side note: This is used extensively in ASP.NET MVC views.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963901/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php/1963912

Comment: Note that the `;` is redundant; as the answers suggest this short-tag expands to an `echo` with a semicolon added to the end, as per the [php documents](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php).

Answer (score 343, accepted):

It's a shorthand for `<?php echo $a; ?>`.

It's enabled by default [since 5.4.0](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.0) regardless of `php.ini` settings.

Comment: Is it available in php 7?

Comment: Note that the final semi-colon is not required. But if, for whatever reason, you need to go back to classic tags, a simple project-wide search/replace `<?=` for `<?php echo` would'nt be enough. Anyway as of today I hope you guys doesn't have any production servers running PHP < 5.6 as this versions are not maintained anymore ([PHP Supported Versions](http://php.net/supported-versions.php)).

Answer (score 63):

It's a shorthand for this:

```
<?php echo $a; ?>
```

They're called short tags; see example #1 in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php).

Answer (score 25):

Since it wouldn't add any value to repeat that it means `echo`, I thought you'd like to see what means in PHP exactly:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 368 // T_OPEN_TAG_WITH_ECHO
            [1] => <?=
            [2] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 309 // T_VARIABLE
            [1] => $a
            [2] => 1
        )
    [2] => ; // UNKNOWN (because it is optional (ignored))
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 369 // T_CLOSE_TAG
            [1] => ?>
            [2] => 1
        )
)
```

You can use this code to test it yourself:

```
$tokens = token_get_all('<?=$a;?>');
print_r($tokens);
foreach($tokens as $token){
    echo token_name((int) $token[0]), PHP_EOL;
}
```

From the [List of Parser Tokens](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php), [here is what T_OPEN_TAG_WITH_ECHO links to](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php).

Comment: The token failed to tell me more details.

Answer (score 14):

`<?= $a ?>` is the same as `<? echo $a; ?>`, just shorthand for convenience.

Answer (score 8):

```
<?=$a; ?>
```

is a shortcut for:

```
<?php echo $a; ?>
```

Answer (score 8):

As of PHP 5.4.0, 
    `<?=   ?>`
are always available even without the short_open_tag set in php.ini.

Furthermore, as of PHP 7.0, The ASP tags:
    `<%, %>` 
and the script tag 
    `<script language="php">` 
are removed from PHP.

Answer (score 5):

It's a shortcut for `<?php echo $a; ?>` if `short_open_tag`s are enabled. Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Answer (score 4):

I hope it doesn't get deprecated. While writing `<? blah code ?>` is fairly unnecessary and confusable with XHTML, `<?=` isn't, for obvious reasons. Unfortunately I don't use it, because short_open_tag seems to be disabled more and more.

**Update:** I do use `<?=` again now, because it is enabled by default with PHP 5.4.0.
See http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php