# Do I need a trailing semicolon here?

Tags: php

Example:

```
<?php $formElement->display()?>
```

Is this fine, or should I provide a ; ?
Well I guess that the PHP interpreter is clever enough to see that the line is finished and the expression done because of the ?> at the end. Right?

Comment: If I learned one thing, this is: Ask experts who know it better than what you believe to see. Might "work", but not be "good", under particular circumstances.

Comment: Even better than asking experts is to check with the Manual first ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is not **required**, but you should put it, as a good practice.

That way, the day you need to add another instruction after this one, it'll work fine.

And here is the manual's page that answers your question : [Instruction separation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php) *(quoting, emphasis mine)* :

As in C or Perl, PHP requires instructions to be terminated with a semicolon at the end of each statement. 

**The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block.** 

The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present.

Comment: If you run the code through the Tokenizer, PHP will not recognize the semicolon. See related answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020445/what-does-mean-in-php/2020668#2020668

Answer (score 6):

No, the closing `?>` will automatically close the line.

From the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php):

> The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block.

Answer (score 4):

As you say, the PHP interpreter will cope as-is.

However, I'd say that adding the semicolon is probably slightly better practice, but that's just a personal coding preference.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: yes. It's okay to only have one statement without a semicolon inside PHP tags.