# Getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';

Tags: php, syntax-error

Here is my code.  I'm new to php and just trying to edit a page using Kompozer.  When I published the site back to the ftp server this error suddenly appeared on the page.  Odd since I didn't even touch this code.  (I have since touched the below code trying to fix it). Any help fixing this code would be much appreciated.

```
   <?php 
     if(isset($_SESSION["pkg_error"]))
   ?>
      <div class="error_msg_cont">
    <?php 
    foreach($_SESSION["pkg_error"] as $error)
    {
    echo $error. "<br>"
    }
    ?></div>
    <?php 
    if(isset($_SESSION["msg"]))
    {
    echo '<div class="error_msg_cont">'. $_SESSION["msg"] .'<div>'
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

On these two lines:

```
echo $error. "<br>" }

echo '<div class="error_msg_cont">'. $_SESSION["msg"] .'<div>' }
```

You need a semicolon before the closing `}`.

[Closing a PHP code block (`?>`) implies a semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2038745/501250), but closing a block of code *within* a PHP code block (`}`) does not.

Comment: I put them in  as follows and get an error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ']'    :                                         echo $error. "<br>"; }

echo '<div class="error_msg_cont">'. $_SESSION["msg"] .'<div>'; }

Answer (score 1):

you missed `;` on :

```
echo $error. "<br>" }
```

and

```
echo '<div class="error_msg_cont">'. $_SESSION["msg"] .'<div>' }
```

Actually, the error is self-explained.

Comment: I've tried putting the semicolon right before the }.  It came out with another error that says: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ']'

Comment: double check other codes. the problem is now elsewhere.