# PHP Session variables not passing but the session ids are the same

Tags: php, session

** SOLVED ** - Server Problem

As mentioned above, the session ids are the same on both pages but I can't access to the session variables. I need Session for a bigger project I created this to test it. I don't have any Idea why since the ids are the same.

First page:

```
<?php session_start();
echo "session started"
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
$_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
echo "Session variables are set.";
echo "<br>";
print_r(session_id());
echo "<br>";
echo "<a href='use.php'>Display</a>"
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Second Page:

```
<?php session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Echo session variables that were set on previous page
echo "Favorite color is " . $_SESSION["favcolor"] . ".<br>";
echo "Favorite animal is " . $_SESSION["favanimal"] . ".";
echo "<br>";
print_r(session_id());
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: Nothing at all like if I declare the variables as an empty string.

Comment: I see the line `echo "<a href='use.php'>Display</a>"` does not end with a semi colon. But that might not be the issue why session not set.

Comment: Tested, Still not working.

Comment: @Rajesh You don't need a `;` on the last line when you close off with `?>`. If you write `<?php echo 'one' ?><?php echo 'two' ?> ` it is still valid. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038745/do-i-need-a-trailing-semicolon-here

Comment: what do you get as the output if you execute `var_dump(is_callable('session_start'));`?

Comment: what does http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php pop out?

Comment: Another possible cause for sessions not working as expected is that you have an accidental whitespace or other output before your first 'session_start() . Please enable error_reporting.

Comment: and how are you accessing this? `http://localhost` or hosted, or as `file:///`? few questions to be answered here in order to get to the bottom of this. When you look at your html source, what do you see, code?

Comment: *Tic ♫ toc ♫ Tic.... Toc ♫* - time is ticking..... so; what's the verdict? I don't have an app for you to install in order to inform me/us as to what the progress is on this question. I feel like I'm watching paint dry. Matter 'o fact, I think it would be more fun. Edit: Ok, I'm outta here; *bye*

Comment: Sorry guys I travelled without Internet access

Comment: @Rajesh bool(true) is the output.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's hosted on the Cardiff university web server.

Comment: @steven I checked that before there is nothing before the session start command.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The output is the following code , nothing strange.

<html class="gr__project_cs_cf_ac_uk"><head></head><body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">

    Favorite color is .<br>Favorite animal is .<br>bool(true)
<br>oqqonnvpqctaccgt241a39dp50
    
    </body><span class="gr__tooltip"><span class="gr__tooltip-content"></span><i class="gr__tooltip-logo"></i><span class="gr__triangle"></span></span></html>

Comment: I tested on the project server which is only accessible with Cardiff uni login. Now I uploaded it to the public server which can be accessed by anyone and it's working. Probably just some kind of server problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those with the same problem:
The problem was that the server( University project server which requires your uni login) required a login to access any file. That login started a session. When I wanted to start another session it just didn't worked. Solution you should use a server which is not requiring a login and than you can start your own session.