# What does the <?= operator mean in php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does '<?=' mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020445/what-does-mean-in-php)

I'm reading someone else's code and I don't think I've come across this before.

```
if((< ? =date("Y");?>-parseInt($('#year').find('option:selected').val()))<18)
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: It's worth noting that the snippet of code you've posted is javascript with embedded PHP.

Comment: *(related)* [What does that symbol mean in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 4):

`<?=` is the short open and echo tag.  [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) is the PHP documentation for it.

Comment: Thank you I looked for it on google and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

`<?=` is short-hand for `<?php echo`, but only works if php.ini is setup properly.

Comment: Or [improperly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/200640/706138), as the case may be

Answer (score 0):

Same as `<?php echo ...`

It is not always enabled in some environments.

Answer (score 0):

That evaluates to:

```
if((<?php echo date("Y"); ?>-parseInt($('#year').find('option:selected').val()))<18)
```

But I think its recommended for you to use `<?php echo '';?>`  instead of `<?= ?>` for compatibility reasons.