# Add domain URL to href and src relative paths

Tags: php, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm using a MVC model and I can invoke webpages with URLs like `http://mywebsite.com/product/productid.html`.
 My folder structure is the following:

- *views* - the views folder
- *js* - the javascript and jquery folder
- *css* - the stylesheets folder
- *images* - the images folder

In *views* folder are contained web pages used to show data to the users. They can include scripts, images and stylesheets. The following snippet is incorrect

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="all" type='text/css' />
```

since the webpage is called with the URL above, and css can't be found with a relative path. To solve the problem, I have defined a `DOMAIN` variable in PHP and changed the code into

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo DOMAIN;?>css/style.css" media="all" type='text/css' />
```

This works, but forces me to add the `<?php echo DOMAIN;?>` snippet to each `href` and `src` attribute on each page. Is it possible to automate it? I've tought to use the `:before` selector but I don't have idea how to use it in this case.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why can't CSS be found with a relative path?

Comment: It's because I am invoking the webpage from an url like `http://mywebsite.com/product/productid.html`. Product is a virtual folder, created with MVC model and .htaccess file. By means of URL, it's at the same level of `css` folder, so if I have a file inside it, I cannot write relative paths: it doesn't actually contain a `css` folder. Hope it's clearer now, otherwise please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:before` only applies to CSS, so that's not of use here.

There's really no way to do automatically add it in PHP that wouldn't be cpu-intensive, and/or require a significantly more complex setup than it sounds like you have right now. Using find-and-replace in your code editor is the best option.

---

Using `<?= DOMAIN; ?>` instead would be shorter, BTW. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020445/what-does-mean-in-php) for more info)