# jQuery .html() with PHP embed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need add some html content to my page. I can do it like this:

```
$("#followUser").html('<label id="followUser"><button class="btn btn-primary" id="followUserButton"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Unfollow</button></label>');
```

But I need to change button text dynamically like

```
$("#followUser").html('<label id="followUser"><button class="btn btn-primary" id="followUserButton"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> <?=$lng['2buttonFollow'];?></button></label>');
```

Second one is my solution but it does not work. Any idea? How to add some php variable by jquery?

**Edit after the problem solved:**
It's about echo part. When I try to use short way of **echo** it makes fail for javascript. 
Actually my solution was true, just changed to **echo**.

Comment: You would have to `echo` the PHP out at the time you deliver the page.

Comment: Does this `<?=` not equal to `<?php echo` ? just wondering.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Do you get an error? What does the generated HTML look like? Are you putting PHP code in a JavaScript file or JavaScript in a PHP file?

Comment: @showdev, i think actually he is trying to change the button text`unfollow` to `follow` dynmically and using PHP for it.

Comment: See: [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

Comment: @Mehmet, would you explain _in the question_ what the difference between these two things? It seems you're making the reader do more work than they should have to do, just to understand the post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're just passing the php variable `$lng['2buttonFollow'];` inside the php tags. Use `echo` to display the value of the variable.

```
$("#followUser").html('<label id="followUser"><button class="btn btn-primary" id="followUserButton"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> <?php echo $lng['2buttonFollow'];?></button></label>');
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful.

Comment: A code only answer like this makes people have to be human diff tools. Explain the differences ... people shouldn't have to play `spot the change`

Comment: It's good that you've worked out the problem from an unclear question, but posting a code-only answer is not ideal. Can you explain _in the answer_ what you have done?

Comment: See: [What does '<?=' mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020445/what-does-mean-in-php)