# I have this two PHP code blocks in one page, but only the first one runs

Tags: php

I have the following two pieces of `PHP` code, both on the same page, but only the first one runs. What seems to be the problem?

**The code**:

```
div class="row" >
  <div class="col-md-12">

  enter code here
  <h1 id="username" style="color:white;text-align:center" >

    <?php
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
   echo $row["username"];}
    ?>
    </h1>

</div>
</div>


<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">

    <h1 id="bash" style="color:blue;text-align:center">

    <?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
   echo $row["bash"];}

    ?>

    </h1>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: try to `echo "test"` in the second php-part without the `if`, to check if you assumption is correct

Comment: It is very likely this question will be closed as you have not provided enough information in regards to the issue. Is your error reporting enabled? If not why not? If yes are any errors showing? Could it be a query error? Have tried debugging or dumping your query data? Tell us what you are trying to do *vs* what is happening.

Comment: Everytime you run `$result->fetch_assoc` you advance the cursor. `$row["bash"]` is the `bash` of row 2. Your question isn't very clear though, so that is just a guess..

Comment: You realize by running fetch_assoc() twice, you are attempting to get two different rows, right?

Comment: @webdeb its works fine

Comment: @Script47 what i am trying to do is i have several column in the database and am trying to print the record inside each one with different style , Thats all

Comment: @Devon "Bash" and "username" is two different column in the database and am trying to print the record inside each one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, be sure to **open and close your HTML tags properly**. Then change your code to the following:

```
<?php
    $username = null;
    $bash = null;
    if ($result -> num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $username = $row["username"];
        $bash = $row["bash"];
    }
?>


<div class = "row" >
    <div class = "col-md-12">
        enter code here
        <h1 id = "username" style = "color:white; text-align:center">
            <?= $username ?> <!-- OR --> <?php echo $username; ?>
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>


<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-12">
        <h1 id = "bash" style = "color:blue; text-align:center">
            <?= $bash ?> <!-- OR --> <?php echo $bash; ?>
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

- There is absolutely no reason **to repeat the same block of PHP code twice** when you can execute it just once.
- You can just **initiate two variables outside the conditional statement** and then change their values based on the result.
- Then, you can just **echo the variables in the `h1` tags you want** to respectively.

**Side note**: For `<?= $variable ?>` to work in versions **< PHP 5.4**, **the short tags must be enabled** in the **`php.ini`** file.

Comment: **ProTip**: You could use `<?= $bash ?>` to `echo` instead of using the full (long winded) method. Just my preferred way/opinion.

Comment: That's a very useful method which I didn't I know of. Thanks a lot @Script47. I'm going to edit the answer.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020445/what-does-mean-in-php).

Comment: Note for that to work in PHP < 5.4 short tags need to be enabled.

Comment: ^ he's right ya know. But if you are using `< 5.4` you ***should*** really update...

Comment: Thanks @chris85. I have updated the answer to include your comment.

Comment: @AngelPolitis , Thank you so much , your answer solve my problem .. you are the best :) And Thanks to every one else for the help <3

Comment: Glad to help @MuhammadCST!