# Echoing variable in php

Tags: php, html

Essentially I am trying to have a heading using what is below. Not sure what is going on but nothing happens.  Even when I do something as simple as echo "hello" there instead of the 2 variables.

```
<h1><?echo "$info[0] ($info[1])";?></h1>
```

Comment: Do you have short tags enabled? Your php may require `<?php` instead. check your browser's "view source" to confirm - if you see php code, then PHP isn't triggering and ISN'T executing your code. unexecuted PHP code send to the browser tends to be treated as bad/invalid html because of the `<...>`

Comment: If you have php 5.4 in *php.ini* the shorthand version of php echo. `<?= "$info[0] ($info[1])" ?>` is enabled by default. [more info here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020445/what-does-mean-in-php)

Comment: Something must be wrong with $info variable. I ran your line and works fine.

    <? $info = array(
  "hello",
  "there"
 ); ?>
    <h1><?echo "$info[0] ($info[1])";?></h1>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<?= ?>` shorthand for echoing variables and the code should look like,

```
<h1><?= "$info[0] ($info[1])"; ?></h1>
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked. Thank you very VERY much :D!

Comment: Glad to know :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way. You are missing `<?php`.

```
<h1> <?php echo $info[0] .'('. $info[1] .')'; ?> </h1>
```