# I do not understand this PHP Code, what is it doing?

Tags: php, oop, ternary

How to read php

i'm learning php, I wrote this.  (It is from a book)

```
   <?php if(!empty($data)):  ?>
        <ul>
             <?php foreach ($data as $dataprint): ?>
                  <li><?= $dataprint ?></li>
             <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
```

I am unable to understand some of the code in this section.
 1. Why are there colons on line 1 and 3?
 2. What does the '<?= $dataprint ?> ) and why does it not have the standard 'PHP' word?
 3. why is there an equal mark in the next?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: 2. is just a [short-hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020445/what-does-mean-in-php) echo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. colons - this is a shorthand version of statements, you should not really learn them at such an early stage. First you need to learn the full versions.
2. `<?= $variable ?>` is a short version of `<?php echo $variable ?>` but means exactly the same.

Also, the shordhand versions from question one are actually not considered a good practice, because when you nest them they are hard to read.

Comment: The only addition I could add to this would be to avoid using shorthand and code it the normal method. Code indenting is always best to practice too so your code is readable.  I am not a fan at all of shortcode for php (but this is personal preference).

Comment: not only that, it is a foundation for MVC approach :) I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Colons on lines 1 and 3 are an alternative way of doing the below code

```
if (!empty($data)) {
    ...
}
```

It makes it a lot cleaner when outputting HTML.

(See http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

`<?=` is a shorthand way of writing `<?php echo`, again it's just an alternative way of doing things.

(See http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can write loops in php many type...
1)eg: if(condition){...code...}else{...code...} or if(condition): means, in place of "{" you can use ":" and for ending the loop use "endif"
2) Your point no 2 is written in shortcode in php for that you have to enabled shortcode in php.ini

Comment: So, we can use if else with ":" without true or false statement, isn't it? (according my code)

Comment: You can use if else loop with condition just the way of writting is different

Comment: your code can be written like this also..                                                    
   <?php if(!empty($data)){  ?>
        <ul>
             <?php foreach ($data as $dataprint){ ?>
                  <li><?php echo $dataprint ?></li>
             <?php } ?>
        </ul>                                                                                                 
       <?php } ?>