# Php submit button not working and error messages not showing up

Tags: php, html, form-submit, contact-form, error-messaging

I am following a tutorial  for creating a contact form with PHP, HTML, and CSS. This is my first time using php and I am having some trouble. [The tutorial is here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1CkBsGhux9U&t=1064) When I try to submit the form to check the error messages, nothing seems to happen. I have no idea whats wrong and have been trying to solve this all day. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The code is for a landing page for a full website that I've been working on.

Here is the HTML and CSS for the code:

```
body {
    font-family:"Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:300;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height:30px;
    color:#777;

}

.emailcontainer {
    max-width:400px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}

#contact input[type="text"], #contact input[type="email"], #contact input[type="tel"], #contact input[type="url"], #contact textarea, #contact button[type="submit"] { font:400 12px/16px "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

#contact {
    background:#F9F9F9;
    padding:25px;
    margin:50px 0;
}

#contact h3 {
    color: #F96;
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

#contact h4 {
    margin:5px 0 15px;
    display:block;
    font-size:13px;
}

fieldset {
    border: medium none !important;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    min-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#contact input[type="text"], #contact input[type="email"], #contact input[type="tel"], #contact input[type="url"], #contact textarea {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    background:#FFF;
    margin:0 0 5px;
    padding:10px;
}

#contact input[type="text"]:hover, #contact input[type="email"]:hover, #contact input[type="tel"]:hover, #contact input[type="url"]:hover, #contact textarea:hover {
    -webkit-transition:border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition:border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    border:1px solid #AAA;
}

#contact textarea {
    height:100px;
    max-width:100%;
  resize:none;
}

#contact button[type="submit"] {
    cursor:pointer;
    width:100%;
    border:none;
    background:#0CF;
    color:#FFF;
    margin:0 0 5px;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:15px;
}

#contact button[type="submit"]:hover {
    background:#09C;
    -webkit-transition:background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition:background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#contact button[type="submit"]:active { box-shadow:inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }

#contact input:focus, #contact textarea:focus {
    outline:0;
    border:1px solid #999;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color:#888;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
 color:#888;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
 color:#888;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
 color:#888;
}
```

.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
        <title> Fiber Optics Engineering Solutions Landing Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Specializing in upgrading and installing optimized fiber optic networks. Upgrade your infrastructure network to the speed of light.">
        <meta name="author" content="Angelo Rodriguez | Apollo Visual Arts">
        <meta name="keywords" content= "Fiber, Optics, Internet, Upgrade, Speed, Networking, Solutions, Fast, Copper">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

</head>

<body>
   <div class="Statement"> <h7>Thanks for visiting Fiber Optic Engineering Solutions. Our full site is currently under maintenance</h7>
    </div>

    <div class="fold">


    <!-- This div is for the landing page pics and log at the upper area of the fold -->
    <div class="fold_high">

        <img id="Logo" src="media/Logo.svg" alt="Fiber Optic Engineering Solutions">

        <div class="fold_pics">

        <img id="pic3" src="media/Landing_Page_Pics/Buildings%20Pic.png" alt="pic3">

        <img id="pic2" src="media/Landing_Page_Pics/Hardware%20Pic.png" alt="pic2">


        <img id="pic1" src="media/Landing_Page_Pics/Data%20Pic.png" alt="data_pic">

        </div>

        <h4>
            UPGRADING YOUR NETWORK TO THE SPEED OF LIGHT
        </h4>
        <ul>

            <li>Interested in improving the overall performance of your network?</li>
            <li>We engineer internal fiber optic networks for any property.</li>
            <li>Maximize the potential of your band width and improve the overall quality of your infrasturcture with <i>Turnkey E.F.I.</i></li>

        </ul>

        <h3>WORK WITH US</h3>
        <img id="arrow"
        src="media/Arrow_down.png" 
        alt="Arrow Down">


        </div> 









    </div>

<?php include('form_process.php'); ?>
<div class="Under_fold">

<div class="container">          
  <form id="contact" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP SELF']; ?>" method="POST">


      <h3>Get in Touch With Us</h3>
    <h4>Contact us today, and get reply with in 24 hours!</h4>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" name="name" value="<?= $name ?>"  autofocus>
    <span class="error"><?=$name_error ?></span>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="text" tabindex="2" name="email" >
    <span class="error"><?=$email_error ?></span>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Your Phone Number" type="text" tabindex="3" name="phone" >
    <span class="error"><?=$phone_error ?></span>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Business Name" type="text" name="bus_name" tabindex="4">
    <span class="error"><?=$bus_name_error ?></span>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <textarea placeholder="Comments or Questions? Type your Message Here...." type="text" name="message" tabindex="5" ></textarea>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>



</div>


        </div>

</body>
```

And here is the code for the php processing page:

```
<?php

print_r ($_POST);
// define variables and set to empty values
$name_error = $email_error = $phone_error = $bus_name_error = "";
$name = $email = $phone = $message = $bus_name = $success = "";

//form is submitted with POST method
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $name_error = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $email_error = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $email_error = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
    $phone_error = "Phone is required";
  } else {
    $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!preg_match("/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i",$phone)) {
      $phone_error = "Invalid phone number"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["bus_name"])) {
    $bus_name_error = "";
  } else {
    $url = test_input($_POST["bus_name"]);
    // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
    if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$url)) {
      $bus_name_error = "Invalid Business Name"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $message = "";
  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }

  if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $phone_error == '' and $url_error == '' ){
      $message_body = '';
      unset($_POST['submit']);
      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
          $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
      }

      $to = 'angelo.rodriguez150@gmail.com';
      $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
      if (mail($to, $subject, $message)){
          $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
          $name = $email = $phone = $message = $bus_name = '';
      }
  }

}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance. Sorry if the code is a little unorganized.

Comment: Can you please supply information on how you are running your code. Console outputs will be required to resolve this issue.

Comment: I would attack the problem this way: verify that error messages will show (try making an intentional syntax error).  After you verify that PHP error messages will show, fix it, and see if the POST variables are being sent.  Best way is to use your browser's console.

Comment: @Jonny `<?=` is a shorthand for `<?php echo`

Comment: `$_SERVER['PHP SELF']` should have a `_` in between: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

Comment: Write these two lines at the top of the html page, in order to display the eventual errors: `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>`. Then give feedback.

Comment: ...how I love it when others make an answer of my comments.

Comment: So you've copied and pasted all the code (3 files) from the tutorial, added a bit of html, then changed _only that one line_ and wonder where the error might be?

Answer (score 0):

Replace **PHP SELF** by **PHP_SELF** in your code like this :

```
    <form id="contact" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
```

Your code should work.

PS : Like **Jeff** said,

```
    <?=
```

is valid, like

```
    <?php
```

Comment: `<?=` is _valid_! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020445/what-does-mean-in-php and [in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)

Comment: Yes, I seen. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with $_SERVER['PHP SELF'] global variable. It should have underscore

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

If you're planning to use shared hosting, it's better to remove this variable completely and have action as blank, server will figure out anyway what to do.

Just to confirm, leave it like this and you're good to go

```
<form id="contact" action="" method="POST">
```

Comment: This was 100% my issue. Thank you so much! I can't believe it was something so small.