# Show Apostrophe (') with sql recset

Tags: php, sql, excel

I do not know what the best option in my case is:

I use a SQL query (built into a php file) to feed na excel chart.

PROBLEM: My first column is made of complex serial numbers (such as 08/18), when excel updates the query, these numbers are automatically transformed into August/18.

BEST SOLUTION (That I can think of):

Edit php file to place a ' before the serial number, that way, when excel updates, it won´t transform into date (I think...)

How can I achieve this?

This is my code:

```
  <? while($sql1_recset = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)) {?>
    <tr>
    <td><?=$sql1_recset['ID'];?></td>
</tr>
<?}?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried a few things, but I do not get PHP:

```
 <td><?{echo("'").echo($sql1_recset['ID']);?}></td>
```

doesn´t work

```
<td><?{echo("'")}&=$sql1_recset['ID'];?></td>
```

doesn´t work

```
 <td><?{echo("'")&$sql1_recset['ID'];?></td>
```

doesn´t work

Comment: `<td><?="'" . $sql1_recset['ID'];?></td>` - See [PHP docs for string operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: Jeee! That was much simpler than I thought! Problem solved! Please answer the question so I can award you and thanks!

Comment: you can also do:
`<?php $id=$sql1_recset['ID']; ?>
<?php echo" '$id' "; ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate strings in php using `.`. Have a read of the [PHP docs for string operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

You've tried two different things so to make this semi-worth the answer, I've included the corrected way of doing both:

1. `<td><?="'" . $sql1_recset['ID'];?></td>` - `<?=` is the [shorthand for echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020445/what-does-mean-in-php), available by default since PHP 5.4
2. `<td><? echo "'" . $sql1_recset['ID']; ?></td>`

Comment: Why not just `<td>'<?=$sql1_recset['ID'];?></td>`?

Comment: Yeah that also works haha @ÁlvaroGonzález, however, it's more situation specific. This gives a more general knowledge on how to concatenate strings, something that OP didn't know how to do before.