# UrlSearchParams.get() doesn't work with rewritten urls

Tags: javascript, query-string, querystringparameter

On my website, I rewrote all my urls. But now I have started using AJAX for a voting functionality (it is a Q&A Community), there are some problems:

I am storing `new UrlSearchParams(window.location.search)` in a constant. Then I call the `.get()` method for this. However, because the urls are rewritten, it doesn't recognize the query.

```
const myParam = urlParams.get('id');
```

The url is `www.example.com/Questions/7` rewritten from `www.example.com/pages/question.php?id=7`

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
Options -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^$ /pages/index.php [L]
RewriteRule    ^users/([0-9]+)$    pages/profile.php?id=$1   [NC]    # Handle users
RewriteRule    ^questions/([0-9]+)$    pages/question.php?id=$1   [NC]    # Handle questions
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z_]+)$       pages/$1.php                    [NC]    # Handle pages
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z_]+)$       pages/$1.html                    [NC]    # Handle pages
```

**How can one overcome the fact that UrlSearchParams will not recognize query string data when the url is rewritten?**

Comment: I used the .htaccess file in the root directory of localhost

Comment: You would have to change it to match the new URL format by parsing `window.location.pathname` instead… or just pass it from PHP in the HTML somewhere, which is probably simpler and more flexible.

Comment: If the URL is rewritten, you can't use the same code to get information from the URL. You need different code. In your case, `location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/'))`...

Comment: Alternative to parsing the pathname is passing a small object variable in a script tag

Comment: Pop this in your `<head>` section ~ `<script>const ID_PARAM = <?= json_encode($_GET['id'] ?? null) ?></script>`

Comment: @Phil this worked. Mind making it into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite-rules all internal rewrites which means the client-side code can only see the original URL, ie `/Questions/7`.

Since your PHP runs server-side and *can* see the rewritten query parameters, you can directly inject them as JS variables for your client-side code to use.

For example, put this in your `<head>` section...

```html
<script>
const ID_PARAM = <?= json_encode($_GET['id'] ?? null) ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: So I can inject _any_ PHP into JavaScript _just_ by using the `json_encode()` function?

Comment: @Marvin `json_encode()` just formats the value in a way safe to use in JS

Comment: And are <?= ?> a variation of php tags within a script tag?

Comment: `<?=` is the same as `<?php echo`. See [What does '<?=' mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020445/what-does-mean-in-php)

Comment: That's brilliant! Also, what do you mean by 'safe to use'? like diminishes a security hole?

Comment: I mean it is formatted correctly; strings are quoted, special characters are escaped, objects and arrays are serialised correctly into their JS counterparts, etc

Comment: Cool. Thanks again.