# How to use a <?php echo urlencode($term);?> tag inside a PHP script

Tags: php

I am trying to include a `<?php echo urlencode($term);?>` tag that works well across every page on my website, but I need to figure out how to make it function inside an existing PHP script that is in the same page.

Below is the example that I am trying to fix. This way the RSS feed will track the keywords that were used in the search automatically.

```php
<?php
// output RSS feed to HTML
output_rss_feed('https://www.speedyfind.net/search/feed.php?Terms=<?php echo urlencode($term);?>', 6, true, true, 200);
?>
```

Comment: Please clarify further what the exact problem is you're having? What is the expected behaviour and what is the output as a result of your current attempt?

Comment: You have <?php ///something   ?> **inside** another <?php ////something ?> ?

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is correct, however you are unnecessarily invoking the `<?php` tag whilst already within one, this is causing the operation to fail.

The correct way to concatenate your `urlencode()` call is to use the `.` operator.

```
output_rss_feed('https://www.speedyfind.net/search/feed.php?Terms=' . urlencode($term) . '', 6, true, true, 200);
```

A side note for future reference, when you are performing one inline operation, you can use the [short open tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020445/what-does-mean-in-php) that echos the result of the operation back to the page.

```php
<?php
echo urlencode($term);
?>
```

is the same as:

```php
<?= urlencode($term) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use <?php tags again to access the $term variable inside php tag. You can access it something like this:

```
<?php

// output RSS feed to HTML

output_rss_feed("https://www.speedyfind.net/search/feed.php?Terms='. urlencode($term) . '", 6, true, true, 200);

?>
```

Comment: Thats what I did and it worked perfectly thanks for the fix all you people who had the answers all of them worked.

Comment: Glad it worked. Could you accept this answer?