# Whats the difference between <?php functionhere(); ?> and <?=functionhere();?>

Tags: php

Can someone explain to me when `<?=` needs to be used or why this programmer would code this way? I'm working on creating a third party module for [SPBAS](http://www.spbas.com/) and I nearly figured it out, I just don't know the significance of the two different options I've specified.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: first one will just call a function, second one will echo what it returns

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this symbol mean in PHP <?=](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963901/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what `<?=something?>` is the short form of doing `<?php echo something; ?>`

where as `<? something; ?>` does whatever `something` was supposed to do

*edit*: im generalizing `something` as any php call, function string, array, object etc..

Comment: Your example is more likely to print out a notice, then the string "something"; while the last example does nothing.

Comment: well if `something` was some function than it would do something hehe

Comment: Sure. But only if called as function()

Answer (score 5):

`<?= functionhere(); ?>` is a short hand for `<?php echo functionhere(); ?>`.

Answer (score 3):

`<?php functionhere(); ?>` does not print out the results from the function, `<?=functionhere(); ?>` does.

Answer (score 3):

This is a shortcut syntax to echo the variable that comes after it. It has the same effect as

```
<?php echo $variable; ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo functionhere(); ?>
```

in your case.

```
<?php functionhere(); ?>
```

will not do anything. unless something is printed out inside the function

For this to work, short_open_tag has to be enabled

Answer (score 2):

`<?= functionhere(); ?>` = `<?php echo functionhere(); ?>`

`<? functionhere(); ?>` = `<?php functionhere(); ?>`

They are called [**short tags**](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) and can be enabled via the PHP configuration.

Answer (score 0):

They do the same thing.  Only difference is `<?php` is proper syntax.
One is short tag for echo - but it should not be used because if this function is turned off it will output your code.  Thanks for the vote down.

Comment: they don't do the same thing.

Comment: and `<?` is proper syntax as well

Comment: I believe the debate is open on this...  Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should.