# <?php, <?, <?=, whats the difference?

Tags: php, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

I don't know if this has been asked before, but here goes: What's the difference between `<?php`, `<?=`, and `<?`?
I'm just curious, and people have been telling me to use `<?php` instead of `<?`, but I just use `<?` because it works for me and it's faster. I ain't seein' no diff'rence (redneck accent for extra pleasures...).

Comment: ... if you *know* it has been asked before, why are you asking instead of looking up previous answers?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963901/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: Check out this question for more information:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Comment: It isn't faster. Just said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<?php` and `<?` are equivalent, except it's generally preferred to use `<?php` since not every server configuration may have the short opening PHP tags option enabled.

`<?=` is a shortcut for echoing back the value of a variable/expression, i. e.

```
<?=$var ?>
```

is similar to

```
<?php echo $var; ?>
```

Comment: The shorter version is also preferred when inserting small snippets of  PHP into normal markup... That's just for readability I suppose...

Comment: Not preferred by me I tells ya! Those damn kids with their short open echo's nowadays :( Get off my lawn!! :)

Comment: @pee - It's true.. I've been shouted at for wasting time refactoring every appearance of `<?`...

Comment: @PeeHaa Actually I *never* use the short version. I ceased to use it the day I read that it may break compatibility with some servers.

Comment: @PeeHaa :D But when you use PHP as the template engine it can make things easier to overview. However, like with many other things: Use it wisely (or not at all, if you prefer ;)). But I don't think they are bad at all.

Comment: @H2CO3 The short-echo-syntax `<?=` is always enabled with 5.4. Nothing will break anymore :)

Comment: @KingCrunch as soon as PHP 5.4 is reasonably spread, you will be right, but many hosting services don't even have 5.3 yet.

Comment: @KingCrunch Well, I'd rather not rely upon **web service providers!** having the most recent versions of PHP. They're lazy and they don't. :)

Comment: @dualed Oh, this argument again ... If your hoster still uses a not-maintained version, you should go and look for a new one! Maybe it's just me, but I wouldn't pay for a hoster, who doesn't care about his costumers. You are right with 5.4, but it will come ;) However, I prefer environments, where I have at least a little bit control about the setup.

Comment: @KingCrunch Well, after all, I just go ahead and write my program in C if PHP gets on my nerves :D

Comment: @KingCrunch if you want to write software that you don't install yourself, you will have to ensure *somehow* that it works on most systems. Using the opening tag that you can not disable instead of the one you can - or even have to enable - is one of the things to do and it does not cost you much.

Comment: @dualed When I'm going to write such software, I don't use the short-tags too, but thats not the point. I would recommend to use a secure environment, because it doesn't make me happy to know, that someone may blame me for being hacked, because he used an insecure setup. It's not hard to find a new, more reliable hoster nowadays. 5.2 is old and unmaintained. I would not write _new_ software for it nowadays.