# Why is <? used for and which is the difference with <?php

Tags: php, ajax

I am learning php and Ajax, but I see a code where `<?` is used.

```
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value=<?=$row['id']?>><?=$row['statename']?></option>
```

Please could you help me to understand why is

Comment: It's commonly called the "short open tag".

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this symbol mean in PHP `<?=`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1963901)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

`<?=$row['statement'] ?>`

as a convenient shorthand to

`<?php echo $row['statement'] ?>`

this can improve readability.

Comment: You are welcome! Please use `htmlentities` to make your application more secure. http://php.net/htmlentities

Comment: thanks, I will see it.

Answer (score 1):

Read the manual.

It will explain everything about tags.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php