# What is the difference between <?= and <?php?

Tags: php, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this symbol mean in PHP <?=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963901/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)
>   [What is the difference between the PHP open tags “<?=” and “<?php”/“<?”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019696/what-is-the-difference-between-the-php-open-tags-and-php)

What is the difference between `<?=` and `<?php` ?

BTW, I searched for `<?=` but nothing comes up. How would you search for `<?=` on Stack Overflow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this symbol mean in PHP <?=](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963901/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) `OR` [What does '<?=' mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020445/what-does-mean-in-php) `OR` [What does <?= mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959256/what-does-mean)